# Is it possible to use Apple's Earbuds/Headphones for audio in Quicktime?

Tags: audio, headphones, quicktime, ear-phones

When I plug in my Apple earbuds to record audio, much like I do on my iPhone for video blogs, I can use the earbuds microphone to record crisper audio than the internal mic. I want to do the same on my Mac.

When I open Quicktime and I select an audio input (whether I'm doing a screen recording or audio recording), it only allows me to select the internal microphone, whether they're plugged in or not.

[image]

I tested to see if it was picking up my earbuds and if I had the speakers on, and take a screenshot. The internal audio mic picks up the noise every time.

Answer (score 1):

A simple google search pulled [this Apple document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201919). According to this, your mac must be equipped to use the Mic and Remote for the Apple Earphones. A simple way to check is to go to System Preferences > Sound > Input.  If there is an "External microphone" listed in the Input tab, your computer can use the microphone included with Apple Earphones with Remote and Mic.